# Weierstrass m test

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\displaystyle f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ when the series converges for all $|z|<R$.
Let  $\displaystyle h(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {a_nz^n}{n!}$.
Show that $h$ is an entire function and that for every $0<r<R$ there is a constant $M_r$ so that $\displaystyle|h(z)| \le M_r\exp\left(\frac {|z|}{r}\right)$ for all $z$.

I tried using the Weierstrass m test on the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {a_nz^n}{n!}$ using that $n!$ is getting larger much faster than $\displaystyle \left(\frac {R}{2}\right)^n$ and after that show that $h(z)$ is entire. Is my idea the right one for this exercise? I want a hint for the rest.

Comment: Could you provide the details? Where do you think your approach fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the series  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n $ converges for $|z|<R$ we deduce that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n |} \leq \frac{1}{R}$ and hence $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{|a_n |}{n!}} =0.$$
Therefore the function $h$ is an entire function.
Moreover $$|h(z)| \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|a_n |}{n!} |z^n | =\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n |r^n  \frac{\left(\frac{|z|}{r}\right)^n}{n!} \leq M_r \exp \left(\frac{|z|}{r}\right)$$ where $$M_r =\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}} |a_n |r^n <\infty.$$